# What is wrong with my xmlstarlet update command?

Tags: xml, windows, xpath, xmlstarlet, quoting

I am trying to edit an element's value in an xml file using [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) but the edit has no effect. No errors are displayed nor any success message.

I have tested my xpath query using an online [xpath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html).

This is my xml file:

```
<workflow scriptid="customworkflow_sktest01">
  <runasadmin>F</runasadmin>
  <workflowstates>
    <workflowstate scriptid="workflowstate15154">
      <description></description>
      <workflowactions triggertype="ONENTRY">
        <setfieldvalueaction scriptid="workflowaction88038">
          <valuejoinfield></valuejoinfield>
          <valueselect>24506</valueselect>
          <valuetext></valuetext>
        </setfieldvalueaction>
      </workflowactions>
    </workflowstate>
  </workflowstates>
</workflow>
```

This is the command I'm using with xmlstarlet:

```
C:\...\xmlstarlet-1.6.1-win32\xmlstarlet-1.6.1>xml edit -P --update "/workflow/workflowstates/workflowstate/workflowactions/setfieldvalueaction[@scriptid="workflowaction88038"]/valueselect" -v 1234 "C:\...\customworkflow_sktest01.xml"
```

When I run that command xmlstarlet simply echoes the unmodified source xml.

**Solution Update:**

The following is the working command:

```
C:\...\xmlstarlet-1.6.1-win32\xmlstarlet-1.6.1>xml edit -P --update "/workflow/workflowstates/workflowstate/workflowactions/setfieldvalueaction[@scriptid='workflowaction88038']/valueselect" -v 1234 "C:\...\customworkflow_sktest01.xml"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to replace

```
"workflowaction88038"
```

by

```
'workflowaction88038'
```

Comment: Good point -- *if* this is on something that behaves like a UNIX shell, those double quotes will be parsed as syntax by the shell, not passed to XMLStarlet and so not treated as part of the XPath. (Given the `C:\\`, I'm not certain whether this is actually the case, but it's a good place to start regardless).

Comment: I'm on Windows, but replacing " with ' did indeed fix things - thank you!

Comment: The double quote parsing under Windows has similar effects to a UNIX shell, although it occurs in libc of the called program, rather than the shell itself.